# How does const char* work when passed an array of char values?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

I'm a bit stumped that passing an array of char values to a const char* prints the entire string literal.

```
void log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << '\n';
}
```

When I dereference 'message' in cout, it prints the first element of the char array passed, which is what I expected; however, the fact that 'message' is a pointer to the whole string literal rather than the first element is confusing me. Why aren't I just getting an address to the first element like I would if I used an int instead of char? Is it something to do with a char being just 1 byte?

Comment: There's an overload of `<<` specifically for `char *` and `const char *` that prints it as a C-style string.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)

Comment: When an array is passed as an argument, the function receives a pointer to the first element of that array. A string literal is represented as a nul terminated array of static storage duration. In the call `log("A")`, the literal `"A"` is an array of two `char` (`'A'` and `'\0'`).  Your function `log()` receives the address of the first `char` in that array (which has value `'A'`). Standard output streams, like `std::cout`, have an `operator<<()` that accepts a `const char *`, ASSUMES it is the address of the first `char` in an array, and prints each `char` until the terminating `'\0'`.